# How to print a concatenated date and time in seconds

Tags: date

How can I print the following date `20150405 12:35:12` in seconds

```
cur_date=20150405
cur_time=12:35:12
cur_datetime=20150405 12:35:12
```

this is what I am doing:

```
    cur_datetime=$cur_date' '$cur_1st_time
    echo "PDT $prev_datetime CRT $cur_datetime"

    cur_date_SEC=`date -d "$(cur_datetime)" +%s`
    prev_date_SEC=`date -d "$(prev_datetime)" +%s`
    echo "CD:$cur_date_SEC PD:$prev_date_SEC"
```

I've also tried

```
`date -d "$prev_datetime" +%s`
`date -d "${prev_datetime}" +%s`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

```
$cur_date=20150405
$cur_time=12:35:12
```

should be

```
cur_date=20150405
cur_time=12:35:12
```

Also, don't use backticks, they're deprecated. The `$(...)` syntax is easier to read, and can be nested, when desired.

Here's a re-write of the "cur" portion of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cur_date=20150405
cur_time=12:35:12

cur_datetime="$cur_date $cur_time"
echo "CRT $cur_datetime"

cur_date_SEC=$(date -d "$cur_datetime" +%s)
echo "CD: $cur_date_SEC"
```

I won't post the output: it will most likely differ from what you'll see, due to timezone differences.

FWIW, [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) can be very handy when writing Bash scripts.